# Error(5,58): PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a trigger to raise an error whenever the number of vaccinated kids are greater than vaccines available in a region.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VERIF_VAC_KID
BEFORE INSERT ON KID_VACCINE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
KIDS NUMBER(6,0);
QUANT NUMBER(6,0);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(K.KID_ID) INTO KIDS, q.Quantity INTO QUANT FROM Kid_vaccine v
inner join Vaccine_quant q ON q._Id = v.Camp_Id where Vp.Svc_Id = :NEW.Camp_Id Group By q.Id, q.Quantity, q.region_ID;
IF(KIDS > QUANT) THEN
Raise_Application_Error(-20207, 'ERROR');
END IF;
END;
/
```

When i run the trigger i get the error

```
Error(5,58): PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

The 'from' seems to be placed correctly, and im clueless of what might me be wrong, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems you need to replace this

```
SELECT COUNT(K.KID_ID) INTO KIDS, q.Quantity INTO QUANT FROM ...
```

with this

```
SELECT COUNT(K.KID_ID), q.Quantity INTO KIDS, QUANT FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I would never find that out

Comment: Is the trigger working now? I have doubt that you might see Mutating Table error.